# python split a bytes string

Tags: python, serial-port, int, byte

So I wrote a code on Python for my scale that is hooked up to my computer via an RS232 - port. Now I got that part working with the following code:

```
import serial

while True:
    ser = serial.Serial('COM2', 9600, timeout = 1)
    print(ser.name)
    ser.write(b'w')
    line = ser.readline()
    print(line)
    ser.close()
```

Whenever I send 'w' in bytes to the scale it sends back the value. That looks like this:

```
COM2
b'       0.000 kg \r\n'
```

It first prints the name of the com-port and on the next line the received data. However. I want to isolate the value(digits) as an int.

I tried using:

```
line = ser.readline()[:-6]
int(line)
```

this gets rid of all the junk "kg  \r\n". And leaves us with just the digits. But of course, Python won't allow me to change a bytes string into an integer. It's probably a stupid beginners question, just like my other two posts but please bear with me, I have only been coding for about 2 weeks now.

Comment: Look into the [`struct` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You guessed that you have to convert (i.e. *decode*) the bytes returned by a serial binary read in to a string, that you can parse further. Using `bytes.decode("ascii")` should do here (no strange chars on sight).

Then, convert to *float*, not *int*. Also, using `str.split` is more robust to changes if you know that the first field is your value:

```
>>> line = b'       0.000 kg \r\n'
>>> value = float(line.split()[0].decode("ascii"))
```

results in `0.0`

Comment: It worked! So you have to decode it in order to convert it. I had to change it up a bit because sometimes the scale sends an empty line when the measured value isn't stable. This would lead into an error.